# Quarto rendering Xaringan

Tags: r, quarto, xaringan

I have a Quarto website created in an R-Studio project and, when rendering a very simple xaringan slides document, I get very different results when the same file is saved in the directory with the quarto site vs outside.

Quick example using the following Rmd code:

````
    ---
    output:
      xaringan::moon_reader:
        css: [default, rladies-fonts, rladies]
        seal: false
    ---
    
    ## Override default theme with other themes
    
    ```yaml
    output:
      xaringan::moon_reader:
        css: [default, rladies-fonts, rladies]
    ```
    
    .pull-left[
    Left-column content
    
    - Lorem
    - Ipsum
    - Bacon
    ]
    
    .pull-right[
    Right-column content
    
    - Lorem
    - Ipsum
    - Bacon
    ]
````

When I save this in a clean directory, and render it with Rmarkdown in a clean session, I get:

[image: result from clean session in clean directory]

However, if I save the file in the directory with the Quarto site, even in a clean session, I get:

[image: results when rendered in directory with Quarto project, but from clean R session]

And, if I open my Quarto site in the r project associated with it, I can render the Rmd file but I get similar flawed output:
[image]

Any thoughts?

Session info:
[image: RStudio session info]

Answer (score 0):

May be try setting the *self_contain* flag to **true** in YAML?
P.S: I only just started using xaringan.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33709207)